# Apache Thrift: Terminate Connection from the Server

Tags: c++, interface, embedded, threadpool, thrift

I am using thrift to provide an interface between a device and a management console. It is possible for there to be up to 4 active connections to the device  at one time, and I have this working using a TThreadPool server.

The issue arises around client disconnections; If a client disconnects correctly, there is no issue, however if one does not (i.e. the client crashes out or doesn't call client->close()) then the server seems to keep that clients thread alive. This means that when the next connection attempt is made, the client hangs, as the server has used up its allocated thread pool so cannot service the new request.

I haven't been able to find any standard, public mechanism by which the server can stop, and hence free up, a clients thread if that client has not used the interface for a set time period?

Is there a standard way to facilitate this in thrift?

Comment: In theory the server should get sooner or later that the connection is broken and return the thread to the pool. Are you able to provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

Set the receive/send timeout on the server socket might help. Server will close the connection on timeout.

https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/129f332d72facda5d06f87e2b4e5e08bea0b6b44/lib/cpp/src/thrift/transport/TServerSocket.h#L103

```
  void setSendTimeout(int sendTimeout);
  void setRecvTimeout(int recvTimeout);
```